# Debian Jessie mySQL 5.5 upgrade to testing 5.6 issues?

Tags: mysql, debian-jessie

I need to upgrade from stable mysql-server5.5.x to 5.6.x on Debian Jessie to run Magneto, but I am also running a high volume forum on 5.5.x. If I enable testing repos and pull 5.6.x (currently 5.6.28-1), will this break some dependencies? I was planning on doing a mock apt-get install and see what it's planning to do first. I hate doing this on a production box, but my choices are limited in this case. If I have issues, is there a sane way to roll back to earlier versions of dependencies and mysql-server5.5 itself?

Answer (score 0):

It worked by adding testing repository, then running `apt-get update`, and then `apt-get -f testing install mysql-server`. It shows you what it's planning to do before it does it, and it just installs mysql 5.6 server and a couple updated libs.